# Запятые вокруг уточнения

Tags: пунктуация

> То, совсем далёкое, время живёт во мне короткими, яркими, почти
>   ослепительными вспышками.

Мне ужасно не нравится обособление "совсем далёкого". Но это авторское. Но автор спорить не будет, если я докажу, что народ его не поймёт...

Кто прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, **совсем далёкое**, время живёт во мне короткими, яркими, почти ослепительными вспышками.

**Авторское обособление оборота**, назначение – подчеркнуть, выделить, остановить внимание читателя на этом факте.

В данном случае обозначить обособление средствами интонации сложно, фактически действует только грамматический принцип постановки запятых.

**Но такие конструкции встречаются**, например: Каждое явление имеет свои, присущие только ему, признаки. Здесь вторая запятая интонационно не читается, но автору нужно выделить оборот, подчеркнуть его значимость.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, *вы* правы. Пусть автор мысленно изменит степень "далёкости" на просто "далёкое", и он сам увидит, что наставил запятых на ровном месте. Если же ему в этом месте авторски необходимо уточняющее насилие над интонацией, то запятые к нему не обязывают (полно правил обособления оборотов, в результате применения которых запятая противоречит интонации) - можно порекомендовать скобки, и если это ему это визуально не понравится, то он передумает.

Comment: Отправлено автору - пусть думает! )))